# How to create schema setup for multiple cities?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, database-design, mongoose-schema

I am going to create a to/do app with the mern stack, I want to have multiple countries and cities in the application.

For the design of the project, should I create a master schema  with a country name and array of cities, with a following array embedded for the type of post.

Then I can use this schema for x countries and thus when  I need to load posts for a user Canada, Vancouver, the posts will be stored in a very specific location, making the search very easy.

If you have experience in this kind of setup, please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create mongoose schema as below.

It will be helpful for your requirements

```
//Country Schema
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Country = new Schema({
    CountryID: { type: String, default: "" },
    Country_Name: { type: String, default: "" },
    Country_Code: { type: String, default: "" },//Mobile
    Country_Currency: { type: String, default: "" },//Business or Ecommerce
    location: { //for Map Purpose
        longitude: Number,
        latitude: Number
    },
    Point: { type: [Number], index: '2d' },
}, { collection: 'Country' });
Country.index({ Point: '2dsphere' });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Country', Country);


//City Schema
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var City = new Schema({
    CityID: { type: String, default: "" },
    CountryID: { type: String, default: "" },
    City_Name: { type: String, default: "" },
    location: { //for Map Purpose
        longitude: Number,
        latitude: Number
    },
    Point: { type: [Number], index: '2d' },
}, { collection: 'City' });
City.index({ Point: '2dsphere' });
module.exports = mongoose.model('City', City);
```

Comment: Sir, can we nest cities inside of country? for example, if I am going to make 5 country application, I can create 5 schema , then for the array of cities I can list all the cities the user can select, therefore when they create a post, if they enter my application selecting I am from Canada , Vancouver, then for the post page, I will have canada schema, and will autofill their city, so they can fill the rest of the form, and when I do GET for the routes of Canada,  we can GET Canada collection, and take all the city of the one the user wants, I am trying to optimize for many city.

Comment: for my needs, its just city and country, then I can search inside of these locations for whatever specific need, but I want to make it easy to know where to search, so if I have 1 million post for different cities, I can make it much more efficent

Comment: insert canada data inside country model with unique country id.

Comment: using canada country id,  add cities inside city example toronto with unique city id

Comment: would it not be better to just have cities for our schema, I was considering maybe it not necceary to have country , then nest city, because for mongodb it is easy to search for 1 city out of 40 city for example, than search for 1 city out of 10 inside a country model, does that make sense?

Comment: if we create search api based on country id in query than it will search only inside country.  if we search directly without country than it will return results from all country